# Computing rank of a row with multiple columns - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to rank group of columns based on amount field. For the same value of the combination fields (Nbr, TypeCd), rank should be same. This needs to be in scala, also spark and scala versions are 1.3 and 2.10 respectively. The code needed is needed in scala.

Sample input data:

```
Id  Nbr    TypeCd   Amt
a1  2010    online  25
a2  2010    online  25
a3  2010    online  15
a4  2011    store   100
a5  2011    store   50
a4  2011    store   90
a6  2011    store   90
a7  2011    store   90
```

Sample output data

```
Id      Nbr    TypeCd   Amt Rank
a1  2010       online   25  1
a2  2010       online   25  1
a3  2010       online   15  3
a4  2011       store    100 1
a5  2011       store    50  5
a4  2011       store    90  2
a6  2011       store    90  2
a7  2011       store    90  2
```

Comment: can you describe in detail the criteria for sorting. I can see in the example that a1 & a4 have different Nbr & TypeCd still they have the same rank. Do you want to compute ranks in subgroups of Nbr & TypeCd ?

Comment: It is not possible to achieve this in 1.3  without converting to RDD.

Comment: Thanks for the response zero323. I'm fine with converting to RDD. I've looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729787/computing-rank-of-a-row/34343061#34343061 and this is based on one field and I need the same using multiple fields like in this case Nbr and TypeCd. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: To be honest an upgrade to >= 1.4 would make more sense. RDD based code doesn't generalize well and the one I've provided for the linked question is addressing different problem (lack of `PARTITION BY clause`).

Comment: In 1.5, there is window functions but as we've 1.3, I can't use them. This is what I'm trying to achieve using the RDDs.

Comment: SELECT 
Id,
DtNbr,
TypeCd,
Amt,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DtNbr,TypeCd ORDER BY Amt DESC) AS Rank

FROM InDataFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an optimal answer, but given your limitations I would do something like this :

```
// Group by Nbr & TypeCd
val groupedData = input.map(x => ((x._2, x._3), x)).groupByKey().map(x => x._2.toList)

// Within each subgroup sort based on the Amount in descending order
val sortedSubGroups = groupedData.map(x => x.sortWith(_._4 > _._4))

// Now assign ranks in each subgroups
val rankAssignedList = sortedSubGroups.map(x => assignRank(x)).flatMap(x => x)
```

Where assignRank, just goes through the list of all elements in the sub groups and assigns ranks as follows :

```
def assignRank(inputList : List[(String, Int, String, Int)]) : List[(String, Int, String, Int, Int)] = 
{
    var rank = 1;
    var prevAmt = 0;
    var elementPosition = 1;
    var outputList = List[(String, Int, String, Int, Int)]();
    for(element <-  inputList)
    {
        // Check if the Current Amount is lesser than Previous one
        if(element._4 != prevAmt)
        {
            rank = elementPosition
        }

        outputList = outputList ::: List((element._1, element._2, element._3, element._4 , rank))
        prevAmt = element._4
        elementPosition = elementPosition + 1
    }

    return outputList
}
```

Comment: It looks close but rank computing logic looks wrong. You cannot blindly increment (otherwise zipWithIndex would work) rank for each element.

Comment: Yes, rank logic doesn't look correct and we can't increment the rank for every row. We need to compare the amt field and if it's same then rank will be same and for the next amt, the rank will change.

Comment: If I can use the below solution by adding multiple columns for partition and sort then that solves my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729787/computing-rank-of-a-row/34343061#34343061

Comment: I see, i had missed the part where you want same rank for elements with similar amounts. That would just mean changing the assignRank method by comparing with previous rank. I think that should be a small change

Comment: I'm new to spark and scala and it would be really helpful if you can please provide the updated code snippet...Thanks so much..

Comment: When I run the above code, I'm getting the below error message. scala.MatchError: [a1,2010,Online,25] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema).

Comment: Any help in resolving this issues with code is very much appreciated

Comment: When I run the above code seems like the  scala.MatchError: is occuring for the below line of code. My input is in Dataframe and I'm converting it to RDD using the below code.

Comment: val input: RDD[(String, Int, String, Int)] = inputdf.select($"Id", $"Nbr", $"TypeCd", $"Amt")
          .map{case Row(id: String, nbr: Int, typeCd: String, amt: Int) => (id, nbr, typeCd, amt) }.....        Is there any error with this statement in converting the dataframe to RDD?.

Comment: I'm able to resolve the issue related to scala.MatchError: above as the error is because of data types mismatch and I've corrected it.

Comment: The last question in this issue is getting the correct rank by comparing the previous amt. If someone can provide the code for that comparing logic to correct the rank it would be great. Thanks so much..

Comment: @user5692277 I have updated the logic to compute rank, can you please verify

Comment: This looks fine and Thanks for all the help.